# GWT calling java from JS doesn't work with Iframe

Tags: gwt, iframe, jsni

I can run Java from JavaScript normally in a GWT application but when I run it in an iframe it doesn't work.

### HTML

```html
<input type="button" onclick="doIT()" value="Do"
    class="fbbotton" style="margin-left: 20px" />
```

### Java

```java
$wnd.doIT = @com.application.client.application::saad();

static void saad()
{
    GWT.log("saad");
}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If both pages are returned from different servers you need to take a look at the same origin policy (in short it is not possible).

If both sites are served from the same server (hostname and port) this should work, but you need to call the function properly.

If your iframe is a child of the page that your javascript is in you need to call: `

```
parent.doIT();
```

Comment: which pages you are talking about ?   I have a page  
html page hosted  in  domain lets say domain1.com
and in this page button when I click on it runs page from other another domain  domain2.com
this page host the js and GWT so both of them in the same page and if I past the URL of this page directly in the browser it works fine but if I run it from Iframe i doesn't work

Comment: this happens within the same iframe?

Comment: on which browsers is this happening?